# using awk to get IP address and name from output of dig -x

Tags: bash, awk

Just trying to make a bash script that will take a list of IP's in a file and then run 'dig -x' against each one, then use awk to get only the IP and hostname it returned and slap that into a new file.

So the IP list is hosts.txt and so far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPLIST="./hosts.txt"

for IP in $( cat $IPLIST ); do
dig -x $IP | awk 'match($0, /192.168.*/) 
{print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

This works well to get the IP addresses from the dig output, but I'm not quite sure how to get the second search term and then spit that out so it's basically:

```
192.168.1.5 == hostname.domain.com
```

The raw output from the dig command is:

```
dig -x 192.168.1.5
<<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 192.168.1.5
global options: +cmd
Got answer:
->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 22854
flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

QUESTION SECTION: 
5.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

AUTHORITY SECTION:
168.192.in-addr.arpa.   300 IN  SOA hostname.domain.com.     
hostmaster.domain.com. 1117231 10800 3600 2419200 300

Query time: 3 msec
SERVER: 10.168.1.20#53(10.168.1.20)
WHEN: Mon Dec  5 13:38:13 2016
MSG SIZE  rcvd: 118
```

Can anyone tell me how to tweak this so that I can format the output with the IP that I have with the hostname on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use parsing this output as you can use `dig +short` to get just the hostname in output.

Your script can be just:

```
#!/bin/bash

iplist="./hosts.txt"

while read -r ip; do
   printf "%s == %s\n" "$ip" "$(dig +short -x $ip)"
done < "$iplist"
```

Comment: That was way prettier than mine. :)
had to drop the '-i' for mine because I was on Mac and that switch doesn't work, but it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be `-r` but even that isn't required in your case.